Why is "a kilogram is 1000g" to infinite sig figs (exact number) but "a liter is equivalent to 1.059qt" not?
Why is "a kilogram is 1000g" accurate to infinite sig figs (an exact number) but "a liter is equivalent to 1.059qt" not?

1 US liquid quart =  0.946352946  liters (exactly)// 1 US dry quart = 1.101220942715  liters (exactly) // 1 imperial quart = 1.1365225 liters  (exactly) // The Winchester quart was about 1.125 L // The reputed quart was about 0.7577 liters // Enjoy your units.

Yu are confounding definitions with actuality. 1. Kg is defined as 1000. grams but 1.00 Kg is not 1000. grams it is 1000+/-10 grams or 1.00x10^3 grams.

Then again, I get 1.057.

@jenny.essex in hindsight your comment was an answer. What caused it to be converted was the statement " I am not sure that is what you are asking". That usually flags that something is intended or should be submitted as a comment rather than an answer.

By definition, 1 kg = 1000 g (k = kilo = 1000)  and 1 L = 1.05668820943 US liquid ounces,  similarly as by definition 1 foot = exactly 12 inches. So the value 1.057 is rounded up and not exact.

1 litre is not even close to 1.059 quarts in many places. Where I am it is around 0.88 quarts.
1 kilo-anything == 1000 anythings by definition of the prefix.

So, "equivalent" is not the same as "equal."

@EmoryRogers What is your definition of quart? One may imagine there is a reference prototype somewhere. Ditto for liter. (I know this is not literally true.) Both can only be known with finite precision, and so is their ratio. On the other hand, the definition of kilogram is exactly 1000.000... grams.

@EmoryRogers It goes further: Scientifically equal is not the same as mathematically equal.


Why is "A kilogram is 1000g" to infinite sig figs (exact number)

This is because humans have agreed to define it this way. There is no other reason. In mathematics, there are things, which are set "by definition."
From 1795 Archives, the gram was defined as follows from Internet Archive:

Gramme, le poids absolu d'un volume d'eau pure égal au cube de la
centième partie du mètre , et à la température de la glace fondante.
Gram, the absolute weight of a volume of pure water equal to the cube
of the hundredth part of a meter, and at the temperature of melting
ice.

You can see the original thoughts and apparent arbitrariness of this unit. With time, it has seen many changes and lately gram and kilogram are now connected to the fundamental constants of nature. Wikipedia has the modern details.
